# Managing folder quota in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, quota

How can I set a quota on specific folders in Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot set quota on a single folder, it can only be done on an entire volume. Also, only members of the Administrators group can set quotas, and the partition must be formatted as NTFS.

To set quotas on a partition:

1. Open My Computer.
2. Right-click on the volume for which you want to assign default quota values and click Properties.
3. Go to the Quota tab and select the "Enable quota management" checkbox.
4. Check the "Limit disk space to" option. This enables the fields for disk space limit and warning levels.
5. Type numeric values into the text fields, select a unit from the dropdown list and click OK. You can use decimal values (for example, 20.5 MB).

   [image]